# YouTube V3 Api not configured - random

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube API v3.
My issue is that for some videos I get status 403 and as response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

I want to point that for some videos it works for some it doesn't work. As example it works for: **https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?part=statistics&id=EdId5Gblfsk&key=XXX** it doesn't work, but for **https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?part=statistics&id=cAs37GavkWM&key=XXX** it works.

For both cases I have same referer. Added print-screen with network requests so you can see that some requests ware ok and other failed ... https://plus.google.com/photos/104666237853903867750/albums/6005884073286705777/6005884077580596402

Comment: are you using a client library?

Comment: No, basic JavaScript used for Chrome Extension. I even tried using REST browser (chrome extension)